# How to get Google play services back to work with new Genymotion 2.7.2?

Tags: android, google-play-services, genymotion

I format my pc and installed Genymotion back except now it is new versions of it.

All worked well with old version of Genymotion when I followed this installation guide 
https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-install-google-services-on-genymotion/en

now I tried to create different versions of virtual devices following same guide but still I can't run my app(it needs google services).

After updating Google play services Google Play store won't respond and other buggy things start to happen. When I run my app again it shows updating Google play services/or download it but the Play store does not open anymore.

Comment: Have you read over this? https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Genymotion-2.0-Emulators-with-Google-Play-support

Comment: I went through over this once again but still won't work

Answer (score 0):

You can create new device custom phone or Google Nexus. I has same problem on virtual Samsung device.